# Correctly handle calls to a function in a module from different threads?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, multithreading

I currently have a .NET application where a function (in a form) calls a public function (located in a module).  The form function (WriteValueToTag) passes some values to the module function (WriteToPLC) and it returns True of False.  The module function (WriteToPLC) is always called from WriteValueToTag (never called directly) and only used from within the form.  However, there is a 3rd party control on the form which raises an event where it calls the WriteValueToTag function.  Therefore, it is called on a separate thread than the main UI form.

The issue I'm having is that (as per my logging) it seems that this function being called simultaneously from different threads sometimes.  And the parameter values appear get out of sync causing an error.  Neither of the functions update any data or control on the form (so I'm not checking for Invoke.Required, etc.) I'm not sure if I should have this check in my functions or launch the WriteToPLC function in its own thread using Thread.Start)?  I've tried to put a SyncLock around the entire contents of the WriteToPLC module function, but this did not seem to help.

How do you handle the calling of a public function in a module, that receives parameters, which can be called at any time from different threads so that it runs uniquely for each thread calling it?  Any examples or links would be helpful. Thank you.

The function declaration in the module looks like this:

```
Public Function WriteToPLC(ByRef PLC As Logix.Controller, ByRef PLCTag As Logix.Tag) As Boolean
```

The subroutine declaration in the form which calls this is:

```
Private Function WriteValueToTag(ByVal PLCTagValue As Object, ByRef PLCTagName As Logix.Tag) As Boolean
```

... in here WriteToPLC is called passing in the appropriate values.

I want to make sure that the ByRef parameter is kept when using Invoke, so I'm not sure if the following code for my WriteValueToTag function is correct:

```
Delegate Function DelegateWriteValueToTag(ByVal PLCTagValue As Object, ByRef PLCTagName As Logix.Tag)

Private Function WriteValueToTag(ByVal PLCTagValue As Object, ByRef PLCTagName As Logix.Tag) As Boolean
    ''Dim writeLock As New Object

    Dim tagName As Logix.Tag = PLCTagName 'remember PLCTagName since it's a ByRef param

    If (InvokeRequired) Then
        Dim newDelegate As New DelegateWriteValueToTag(AddressOf WriteValueToTag)
        Dim eventArgs() As Object = {PLCTagValue, tagName}
        Log.Debug("Calling Function WriteValueToTag() via InvokeRequired")
        Dim result As Boolean
        result = CType(Invoke(newDelegate, eventArgs), Boolean)
        PLCTagName.Value = tagName.Value 'put value back in since PLCTagName param is passed ByRef
        Return result
    Else
        Try
            Log.Debug("Entering Function WriteValueToTag()")
            Log.Debug("  writing value {0} to tag {1}", PLCTagValue, tagName.Name)

            PLCTagName.Value = PLCTagValue

            Return(WriteToPLC(mPLC, PLCTagName))
        Catch ex As Exception
            HandleError(ex, False)
            Return False
        End Try
    End If
End Function
```

Would this be the correct way to invoke WriteValueToTag to retain the ByRef parameter?  I was wondering since I'm using "eventArgs()" to pass the variables, which is an object, will this will pass a reference to the object (even if the parameter for Invoke is declared ByVal).  If this is true, do I still need to declare any local variable tagName to store this value and then set it back after the Invoke?

Also wondering if it would be just as simple as this:

```
 If (InvokeRequired) Then
        Dim newDelegate As New DelegateWriteValueToTag(AddressOf WriteValueToTag)
        Dim eventArgs() As Object = {PLCTagValue, PLCTagName}
        Log.Debug("Calling Function WriteValueToTag() via InvokeRequired")
        Dim result As Boolean
        result = CType(Invoke(newDelegate, eventArgs), Boolean)
        PLCTagName.Value = PLCTagValue 'retain PLCTagName.Value as it's passed ByRef and Invoke will not change it
        Return result
```

...

Comment: I have a feeling the problem isn't with "parameters getting mixed up" (each thread has its own call stack to keep track of parameters being passed to methods).  The problem is probably within WriteToPLC itself - whatever it is doing, only one thread should be doing it at a time.

Comment: @mbeckish - agreed.  So, how then can I make sure that WriteToPLC only does what it's supposed to for each thread calling it?

Comment: Since you didn't show what `WriteToPLC` does or explain specifically what it's doing wrong, that's impossible to say...

Comment: By any chance, are you calling `Application.DoEvents()` anywhere?  Or are you doing anything within `WriteValueToTag` that would directly or indirectly cause the 3rd-party control to fire?  What makes you think there is more than one thread involved?  Can you verify that by setting a breakpoint and viewing your thread list in Visual Studio?

Comment: I would implement the [Producer / Consumer pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228601(v=vs.110).aspx).  Your threads calling ` WriteToPLC` should instead place a request object in the queue.  Have only 1 consumer thread go through the requests and make the actual calls to `WriteToPLC`, one at a time.

Comment: @mbeckish - Thank you.  I will consider the Producer/Consumer pattern for the threads.  At this time, I went ahead and added a check if InvokeRequired in the WriteValueToTag function as it's called from different threads and this so far seems to have helped.  I will wait to see if it completely resolves the issue as I monitor the logs for the application.

Comment: @adv12 - I write to a log when the function is entered and specify the thread id, calling function, etc.  This shows me that it is being called by another thread (in this case the 3rd party control event).  I am not using or calling Application.DoEvents anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me how this question is a C# question. What little code is shown appears to be VB.NET code. But, here's a C# version of your answer…

There are a variety of ways you can ensure that a library method is called only by one thread at a time. And frankly, lacking [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows exactly how your scenario works, it's impossible to know for sure what the best approach would be.

But in a Windows Forms program the most common, and in some cases only correct, approach is to simply ensure all calls are made using the main UI thread. This is accomplished using the `Control.Invoke()` method.

Without a good code example, it's not possible to know what your code actually looks like. But the basic idea would be to modify your `WriteValueToTag()` method so that it looks something like this:

```
private void WriteValueToTag(object PLCTagValue, ref Logix.Tag PLCTagName)
{
    Logix.Tag tagName = PLCTagName;

    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => WriteValueToTagImpl(PLCTagValue, ref tagName)));
    PLCTagName = tagName;
}

private void WriteValueToTagImpl(object PLCTagValue, ref Logix.Tag PLCTagName)
{
    // original method body here
}
```

You could of course implement it all in a single named method, putting the "…Impl" method body into an anonymous method in the original. Either works fine.

Note though that if you put the original method body into an anonymous method, you will have to use `tagName` in that method body instead of `PLCTagName`, as you can't use by-reference parameters (`ref` or `out`) in the body of an anonymous method (that's why the parameter has to be copied to a local before calling `Invoke()`, and then the local copied back to the parameter when the call returns).

The main thing here is that no matter who calls that method, the actual work of the method will always be executed in the main UI thread, ensuring both that the method is only ever executed by a single thread at a time, and that it's executed in the main thread (in case some or all of the difficulty is in fact a "thread affinity" issue instead of simply a synchronization issue).

**EDIT:**
In answer to your question about VB.NET, no…I don't feel that the code you tried will work. It certainly is not semantically equivalent to the above, and unless the passing by-reference is superfluous, it won't accomplish the correct results.

Note also that it is IMHO incorrect and useless to ever use the `InvokeRequired` property. It just makes the code extra redundant. Instead, just always call `Invoke()`. It will do the right thing according to the thread you're on. For more on that point, see [MSDN’s canonical technique for using Control.Invoke is lame](http://blogs.msmvps.com/duniho/2008/09/12/msdn-s-canonical-technique-for-using-control-invoke-is-lame/).

Here is a VB.NET implementation structured the same as my example above, but using your own method body as the starting point:

```
Private Function WriteValueToTag(ByVal PLCTagValue As Object, ByRef PLCTagName As Logix.Tag) As Boolean

    Dim tagName As Logix.Tag = PLCTagName 'remember PLCTagName since it's a ByRef param
    Dim result As Boolean

    Invoke(CType(
    (
        Sub()
            Try
                Log.Debug("Entering Function WriteValueToTag()")
                Log.Debug("  writing value {0} to tag {1}", PLCTagValue, tagName.Name)

                tagName.Value = PLCTagValue
                result = WriteToPLC(mPLC, tagName)
            Catch ex As Exception
                HandleError(ex, False)
                result = False
            End Try
        End Sub
    ), MethodInvoker))

    PLCTagName = tagName
    Return result
End Function
```

It is possible to handle by-reference parameters directly when calling `Control.Invoke()`. To do so, you need to retrieve the updated values from the original `args` array passed to the `Invoke()` method; the element value(s) will be updated according to whatever modification the called method made. But it is my preference to deal with them as above. I find this syntax, where the delegate being invoked is always a parameterless `void` method (i.e. `Sub()`) and the handling of return value and by-reference parameters is put into the anonymous method body itself, to be clearer and easier to generalize.

Comment: I figured I could translate the C# to VB.NET, but this might be a bit different.  I have updated my original post to show my entire WriteValueToTag function.  Is my code correct to handle the ByRef parameter passed in when using the Invoke method?